# Operatornorm of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint, positive definite operator in $H$ with $\inf\, \text{spec}(A)\geq 1$. I want to show that it is equivalent to the conditions that $A$ is invertible and $||A^{-1}||\leq1$. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|\lambda| <1$ then $\|\lambda A^{-1}\| <1$. For any operator $S$ with $\|S\| <1$ the operator $(I-S)$ is invertible (the inverse being $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S^{n}$). Hence $I-\lambda A^{-1}$ is invertible which implies that $A-\lambda I$ is invertible. Hence $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $A$.

This proves that $|\lambda| \geq 1$ for every $\lambda$ in the spectrum. The spectrum of a positive operator is contained in $[0,\infty)$. Hence $\lambda \geq 1$.

Comment: can you explain the first sentence?

Comment: The first sentence is $\| \lambda A^{-1}\|=|\lambda| \|A^{-1}\| <1$ because $\|A^{-1}\| \leq 1$

Comment: what is with $\lambda<-1$?

Comment: @ShaqAttack1337 See the edited part of my answer.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I have edited my answer too.

Comment: Can you explain why $I-\lambda A^{-1}$ being invertible implies that $A-\lambda I$ is invertible?

Comment: $A-\lambda I=A(I-\lambda A^{-1})$ and product of two invertible operators is always invertible.

Comment: ah and $A$ is invertible by hypothesis...